# C#, What's the proper syntax for calling an Expression<Func<T-in, T-out>> from within another lambda expression?

Tags: entity-framework-5, lambda

I'm working in Entity Framework 5 and having problems creating an expression to use inside a method.

I believe the problem is that normally I would call the expression in a lambda expression such as `dbContext.Counties.Select(GetLargeCities())`, but in the code I am working with, I am projecting the Counties entity into a view model called CountyWithCities. Where I would normally call the expression, I have a singleton `c` and don't know how to call the expression there.

The reason I want to accomplish this using an expression is because I want the `GetCountiesWithCities` method to hit the database once, with Entity Framework constructing a complex graph for all the objects in the result.

For some reason the code below is producing the error `The name 'GetLargeCities' does not exist in the current context."

```cs
    public class CountyWithCities // this is a view model
    {
        public int CountyID { get; set; }
        public string CountyName { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<City> Cities { get; set; }
    }

    public class City // this is an entity
    {
        public int CityID { get; set; }
        public string CityName { get; set; }
        public int Population { get; set; }
    }

    public IEnumerable<CountyWithCities> GetCountiesWithCities(int StateID)
    {
        return dbContext.States
            .Where(s => s.StateID = StateID)
            .Select(s => s.Counties)
            .Select(c => new CountyWithCities
            {
                CountyID = c.CountyID,
                CountyName = c.CountyName,
                Cities = GetLargeCities(c) // How do I call the expression here?
            });
    }

    public Expression<Func<County, IEnumerable<City>>> GetLargeCities = county =>
        county.Cities.Where(city => city.Population > 50000);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I normally do this with an extension method.

```
public static IQueriable<City> LargeCities(this IQueriable<County> counties){
    return counties
        .SelectMany(county=>county.Cities.Where(c=>c.Population > 50000));
}
```

usage:

```
dbContext.Counties.LargeCities()


   public IEnumerable<CountyWithCities> GetCountiesWithCities(int StateID)
    {
        return dbContext.States
            .Where(s => s.StateID = StateID)
            .Select(s => s.Counties)
            .LargeCities()
            .GroupBy(c=>c.County)
            .Select(c => new CountyWithCities
            {
                CountyID = g.Key.CountyID,
                CountyName = g.Key.CountyName,
                Cities = g.AsQueriable() // i cant remember the exact syntax here but you need the list from the group
            });
    }
```

Comment: Luke, I tried you answer, but it throws `LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable\`1[MyData.County] GetLargeCities()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.` Perhaps my problem is that I am attempting to use the method _inside_ the projection `.Select(c => new CountyWithCities { })`. I also noticed that despite typing the extension method as `IQueryable<City>` the error says the method is returning `IEnumerable<City>`.

Comment: Quoting this answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/4044751/125292) "Compiled functions can't be converted to SQL, only expressions can." So I don't think an extension method would work here. I wish that were not the case.

Comment: You cant call it in the middle of a lambda but you can use it as part of a chain of queries which will be executed at once. Ive included a sugguested way of using this (its off the top of my head so syntax ext may not be quite right)

Comment: Luke, I'm specifically looking for a way of calling an expression from within the middle of a lambda. On the other hand, you're answer showed me how to maintain the IQueryable across chainable methods (`this IQueryable<T> source`). I appreciate your help.

Comment: @Kuyenda the only way i know of to actually call an expression inside a lambda is with a reusable expression tree. Linqkit allows this but its a bit of work